# prevent renaming of vector elements assigned from another vector

Tags: r

I have a character vector (in this case, hex colors).

```
somePalette <- structure( c( "#F6B436", "#4D86A0","#672767"), 
                          .Names = c("Yellow", "Blue", "Purple")
  )
pie(c(1,1,1),col=somePalette)
```

From this vector, I wish to choose a few elements to pass to another vector (in this case, for use as the `values=` argument to `ggplot2::scale_color_manual`).

```
cols <- c("setosa" = somePalette["Yellow"],
          "versicolor" = somePalette["Blue"],
          "virginica" =  somePalette["Purple"])

# This doesn't work
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, col = Species)) +
  geom_point(size=5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=cols)
```

It seems that the element names I tried to assign have been changed, depending on the index of the element I passed:

```
> print(cols)
   setosa.Yellow  versicolor.Blue virginica.Purple 
       "#F6B436"        "#4D86A0"        "#672767"
```

The following workaround produces the desired output:

```
# This works, though
cols2 <- c("setosa" = "#F6B436",
           "versicolor" = "#4D86A0",
           "virginica" =  "#672767")
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, col = Species)) +
  geom_point(size=5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=cols2)
```

Why does this renaming happen?  (If it's not a bug, a link to documentation on this behavior would be much appreciated.)  What's the easiest way to stop it from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This happens because the people who wrote the [`c()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html) function designed it that way. Personally, I don't see any strong rationale for it; I'd prefer if the names of operand vectors be stripped when an explicit name is specified in the enclosing `c()` call.
- I can't find any documentation on this behavior.
- I can think of the following approaches to stop it from happening:

---

**1:** [`unname()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unname.html).

```
c(setosa=unname(somePalette['Yellow']),versicolor=unname(somePalette['Blue']),virginica=unname(somePalette['Purple']));
##     setosa versicolor  virginica
##  "#F6B436"  "#4D86A0"  "#672767"
```

**2:** [`[[`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) indexing.

```
c(setosa=somePalette[['Yellow']],versicolor=somePalette[['Blue']],virginica=somePalette[['Purple']]);
##     setosa versicolor  virginica
##  "#F6B436"  "#4D86A0"  "#672767"
```

> The usual form of indexing is [. [[ can be used to select a single element dropping names, whereas [ keeps them, e.g., in c(abc = 123)[1].

**3:** [`setNames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/setNames.html) afterward.

```
setNames(c(somePalette['Yellow'],somePalette['Blue'],somePalette['Purple']),c('setosa','versicolor','virginica'));
##     setosa versicolor  virginica
##  "#F6B436"  "#4D86A0"  "#672767"
```

Comment: I like the `setNames` solution, but a less verbose way would be: `setNames(somePalette[c('Yellow', 'Blue', 'Purple')], c('setosa','versicolor','virginica'))` upvoted!

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer and also to @arvi1000, I also like the concise setnames version, much more manageable in my actual use case.